# Typescript return typeof of "this"

Tags: javascript, typescript

I use a library called Foo that you use by extending any other class.
All methods of Foo return this.

So Typescript should understand that `fromJson` is the same type of the class `BarFoo` but it doesn't

```
// library
class Foo {
    fromJson(obj:any) {
        if(obj == null) return obj;
        Object.assign(this, obj)
        // something else here
        return this;
    }
}
// usage
class BarFoo extends Foo{
    id:string
    foo(){

    }
}
const barFoo = new BarFoo().fromJson({id: 'foo'})
barFoo.foo(); // should have autocompleted foo()
barFoo.somethingNotExisting(); // should have errored out
```

Comment: That function could return `obj` which is `any` or `this`. `this` is a subtype of `any`, so the functions return type is `any`.

Comment: You can simplify the function to `fromJson(obj:any) { return Object.assign(this, obj); }` which eliminates all ambiguity. Even the `null` check is obsolete because `Object.assign` can deal with `null` as a source.

Comment: @Thomas @Aluan this function does more than Object.assign that's why I commented   `// something else here` I removed it because it is irrelevant for the question, however, the `null` check is necessary for the "something else"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem here is the first return: `if(obj == null) return obj;`.
Typescript is inferring that the return type of `fromJson` is `any`.

You can solve it returning `null` directly: `if(obj == null) return null;` or annotating the method with the return type `fromJson(obj: any): this {`.

Be aware that with both solutions you end up having a possible null returned from the method. So the real return type whould be `this | null`.

Answer (score 2):

Since you also have a case of return null which means the correct type should be `this | null`:

```js
class Foo {
    fromJson(obj: any): this | null {
      //
    }
}
```

So to use with `strict` mode enabled in `tsconfig.json`, you might have to check nullable before using:

```js
const barFoo = new BarFoo().fromJson({id: 'foo'})
barFoo?.foo()
```